# Combine 2D arrays with different shape into a 3D array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to combine 2 2D arrays with different size into a 3D array like this:

```
a1 = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1]])
print(a1.shape) #(2,6)

a2 = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]])
print(a2.shape) #(2,4)

combined = np.stack((a1,a2)) #ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

I'm trying to get the following:

```
>>> [[[0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]]]
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: The dimensions of an n-d array must be expressible as a tuple `(d1, d2, ..., dn)`. How do you propose your scheme to be able to do that?

Comment: you're getting the error because you can't do that with numpy arrays. Any given dimension must always be the same length throughout the array.

Comment: Perhaps you can set the empty values to `-1` or `NaN` instead.

Comment: That's a list of lists, not a 3d array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a non-rectangular shape arrays in numpy. Now you have some options depending on what you are trying to achieve:

1. Use lists:

   ```
   combined = [a1.tolist(), a2.tolist()]
   #[[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]]
   ```
2. Use a list of arrays:

   ```
   combined = [a1, a2]
   #[array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]), array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1]]])]
   ```
3. Use an array of lists:

   ```
   combined = np.array([a1.tolist(), a2.tolist()])
   #[[[list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])]], [[list([0, 0, 0, 0]) list([1, 1, 1, 1])]]]
   ```

I would suggest using lists, since there is not much benefit of using numpy when elements are objects like lists.

Answer (score 0):

As the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) tell, the arrays must be of the same shape. Try this:-

```
a1 = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1]])
print(a1.shape) #(2,6)

# notice extra 2's and 3's to make it of same shape as a1
a2 = np.array([[0,0,0,0,2,2],[1,1,1,1,3,3]]) 
print(a2.shape) #(2,4)

combined = np.stack((a1,a2))
```

To get this :-

```
[[[0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]]]
```

you can try python lists.
And if you want to stick to numpy arrays try padding the a2 array with 0 or something, otherwise shape mismatch of a1 and a2 won't stack them along the third dimension.

Which final array should it make:- 2x4x2 (as per a2 shape) or 2x6x2 (as per a1 shape)?
Since both have different shapes.

Comment: This answer does not help OP to get what they are looking for.